# Uploaded Photo not showing up in page FACEBOOK SDK 5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am using PHP FACEBOOK SDK 5 to upload images on a facebook page, as follows:

```
$imgData = [
    'url'          => 'http://www.lonuevodehoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/imagenes-graciosas.jpg',
    'caption'      => 'Caption pa la fotito'
];
$uploadImg = $fb->post('/'.PAGE_ID.'/photos', $imgData, PAGE_TOKEN);
```

And it returns success message:

```
$uploadImgRes=$uploadImg->getDecodedBody();
print_r($uploadImgRes);
```

**Returns:** Array ( [id] => 1638550629765190 [post_id] => 1636201980000055_1638550629765190 )

But then there is no visible photo anywhere. Not the page and not on my own timeline neither.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

For gurther debugging, I am attaching the created Image on a normal post, as follows:

```
$linkData = [
  'message' => 'Just whatever',
  'object_attachment' => 1638548446432075
];
$response = $fb->post('/'.PAGE_ID.'/feed', $linkData, PAGE_TOKEN);
```

And this is posting the "Just whatever" text, but not the attachment.

And what's even more, this kind of posts (the one with attachments) are only vivible if I access the page via Admin on the browser, but they are hidden if I Log In as the Page itself.

As TOKEN, I am using the token assigned to the page after doing /me/accounts on the graph API.

Comment: Is your app public yet? (See top of Status&Review-tab in app dashboard.)

Comment: Yes, it is public. Since normal text posts are working fine. (Thank you)

Comment: Can you request details for the post using the id you got returned in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)?

Comment: @CBroe I read the documentation but I don't understand how to proceed with getting post details given ID, how should I do? Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: I meant that as a debugging measure only. Select your app in Graph API Explorer, get an access token, and then copy&paste the post id into main request field – and see what result you get. But if you’re not familiar with GAE, then this is probably too broad.

Comment: @CBroe Okay, thank you :) I got it now and something strange is happening. When using the ID output by the script, it says: Unsupported get request.... But when using another ID (which I manually got from a different picture), it outputs: created_time and id. So, the problem is that the id being returned on my script is not a real one. But, how can I know where the problem is, and why is it even returning an ID then? Thank you very much for your time, seriously.

Comment: @CBroe Updated with more info. And, by the way. My APP is not reviewed because it is not public-oriented. Should it be reviewed for this to work right or is that not necessary (as I am assuming)? Thanks again.

Comment: It does not need to be reviewed, if you are only going to ask people with a role on the app for permissions. It needs to be set to “public” though – otherwise any content created via it will not b visible to others.